# When raspberry pi is connected via ethernet cable and wifi?

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, gsm

I recently noticed when I connect my RaspberryPi via Ethernet cable and WiFi, there were two IP addresses assigned to it.

Questions:

1. Is it some kind of error or It works that way?
2. Is it possible to connect RaspberryPi via ethernet cable to one internet connection and via USB WiFi dongle to another connection? If any of the connection is down(no internet connectivity), RaspberryPi should be able to connect to another one?
3. If it is possible to achieve scenario explained in Question 2 I would like to configure a 3G dongle connection.

Comment: Yes, it is normal to have two `different` IP addresses assigned to two `different` interfaces. For sharing ethernet connection over wifi spot, you should look at this, http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot. For 3G part of the question, instead of using `eth0` as interface in above link, replace it by ppp0 (or relevant) and you should be good to go. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If a system has more than one active network interface, it is expected to get an IP for each one. Now, which one is used when you do a network operation, depends on you **routing** configuration.

Take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/304372/how-can-i-tell-which-of-multiple-network-cards-is-in-use) for more info about several interfaces in general (it's not a specific rpi subject but a general one).